# UWP JS Target version 15063 and 16299 Visual Studio Debugging doesnt work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, project-settings, creators-update

I'm working on UWP + JS project and the current target version is Windows  10 14393. If I change the the target version to higher like 15063 or 16299, The debugger is never hit on the managed code. The Managed code part is done as Windows runtime library project which is references from the JS UI project.

The app code is actully working out the logic and inserting the entries to DB and also runs the Background jobs such that the Web services called from there are actually hit.

I used to get the debugger hit with target version being 14393. I created the project with VS2015 and now using VS2017. Is there something I'm missing.

I got an error in event viewer too.

```
Error Information
AppInsightsEvent Name = vs/ml/proppages/appdesigner/prop-page-designer-view-fault
          Description = UnLoadPage
     TelemetrySession = 'a99ea967-776a-4b5b-9827-a1455f2d038c' Started = True OptIn=True IsInitialized = True Cloned = False
             UTC time = 2017-11-30T07:04:12

 Exception:
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException
 COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
 System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IPropertyPage.SetObjects(UInt32 cObjects, Object[] ppunk)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropPageDesigner.PropPageDesignerView.UnLoadPage()
Telemetry Session Shared Properties:
   VS.Core.User.PersonalizationVsid = 53f18ce0-5506-49b6-9592-0e875939da6c
   VS.Core.Machine.Id = 5dc43e02-8218-43ea-9c39-40eb071ccc6d
   VS.Core.CampaignId = 1063988796.1498629385
   VS.Core.ChannelManifestId = VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.5+27004.2010
   VS.Core.TelemetryApi.ProductVersion = 15.4.812-master70992889
   VS.Core.User.Type = External
   VS.Core.BuildNumber = 27004
   VS.ABExp.Flights = vswpkgfailuredlg;spmoretempsbtn1;fwlargebuffer;refactoring;tn-none-15b;asloff;tn-vsmacnps-7;lazytoolboxinit
   VS.Core.MacAddressHash = 75c571fb6d335e7e8bfb4ca1530af2627ea9f52e14b0d13398729a2313e161c2
   VS.Core.User.Location.GeoId = 244
   VS.Core.SkuName = VS Pro
   VS.Core.BranchName = D15SVC
   VS.Core.OS.Version = 10.0.16299.64
   VS.Core.ProcessId = 1316
   VS.Core.User.IsMicrosoftInternal = False
   VS.Core.User.Id = b8c45cea-f450-480c-b2b7-fcf021b9d55e
   VS.Core.Locale.ProductLocaleName = en-US
   VS.Core.ChannelId = VisualStudio.15.Release
   VS.Core.ExeVersion = 15.0.27004.2010
   VS.Core.ExeName = devenv
   VS.Core.ManifestId = VisualStudio/15.4.5+27004.2010
   VS.Core.User.IsOptedIn = True
Telemetry event 'vs/ml/proppages/appdesigner/prop-page-designer-view-fault' properties:
   [VS.Fault.Exception.MethodDef] = '35b'
   [VS.Fault.Exception.AppStamp] = '5a139b43'
   [VS.Fault.Exception.ModStamp] = 'd54e03bb'
   [VS.Fault.Exception.Offset] = '24'
   [VS.Fault.Exception.ModuleVersion] = '15.3.0.0'
   [VS.Fault.WatsonOptIn] = 'Unspecified'
   [VS.Fault.WatsonReportNumber] = '1'
Telemetry event 'vs/ml/proppages/appdesigner/prop-page-designer-view-fault' reserved properties:
   [DataModel.Severity] = '10'
   [DataModel.Source] = 'DataModelApi'
   [DataModel.EntityType] = 'Fault'
   [DataModel.EntitySchemaVersion] = '5'
   [DataModel.CorrelationId] = 'ad0ded45-99aa-42a5-bc7c-381366c577a9'
   [DataModel.ProductName] = 'vs'
   [DataModel.FeatureName] = 'ml/proppages/appdesigner'
   [DataModel.EntityName] = 'prop-page-designer-view-fault'
   [DataModel.Fault.Exception.TypeString] = 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException'
   [DataModel.Fault.Exception.Message] = 'COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.'
   [DataModel.Fault.Exception.StackTrace] = 'System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object,IntPtr,IntPtr&,Boolean&)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IPropertyPage.SetObjects(UInt32,Object[])
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropPageDesigner.PropPageDesignerView.UnLoadPage()'
   [DataModel.Fault.Exception.ErrorCode] = '-2146233049'
   [DataModel.Fault.Description] = 'UnLoadPage'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam1] = 'devenv.exe'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam2] = '15.0.27004.2010'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam3] = 'vs.ml.proppages.appdesigner.prop-page-designer-view-fault'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam4] = 'RXOEJIH3RSKJEZ4XXWPXUDKCPPWJODNG'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam5] = 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppDesigner'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam6] = 'System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW'
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam7] = ''
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam8] = ''
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam9] = ''
   [DataModel.Fault.BucketParam10] = ''
   [DataModel.Fault.IsSampled] = 'True'
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the setting of debugging type? Project \ Debugger \ Debugger Type :  "Managed Only", "Mixed", "Script", etc...

Comment: @pnp0a03 yep. Its Managed. Is it working for you? I'm specifically meaning Target version 15063 or +

Comment: @JinsPeter Try use "Mixed" debugger type. By the way, what's your OS version?

Comment: @BarryWang My OS is Windows 16299

Comment: @JinsPeter I cannot reproduce this from my Visual Studio. You'd better report it to here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html